# the Perl's __PACKAGE__ special word, can not use as namespace?

Tags: perl

i see the `__PACKAGE__` will be compiled as package name .

so why the code :

```
Foo::bar()
```

can work. but the code:

```
__PACKAGE__::bar()
```

will produce an error :

```
Undefined subroutine &__PACAKGE__::bar called
```

where the caller is in the Foo package, so the `__PACKAGE__` will be Foo;

hope you can explain this :)

let me add an example to explain the scenior:

```
$ perl -e 'package Foo ; sub bar { print "hello\n" } ; __PACKAGE__::bar()'  
Undefined subroutine &__PACKAGE__::bar called at -e line 1.

$ perl -e 'package Foo ; sub bar { print "hello\n" } ; Foo::bar()'
hello
```

Comment: use \_\_PACKAGE__->bar() insteaf of \_\_PACKAGE__::bar()

Comment: Bad advice. That calls `bar` a method, not a sub call.

Comment: My solution works, the bar() sub receives now the package name. Knowing this, there is no problem

Comment: @Miguel Prz, It can call subs other than `__PACKAGE__`'s `bar` and passes the wrong arguments. Knowing about (half) the problems doesn't make them disappear. You're giving even more bad advice. As I've already stated, the correct way to call `bar` in the package returned by `__PACKAGE__` is `bar()`.

Comment: my comment (no answer) was in the way of how can we use \_\_PACKAGE__, I see your point, but my goal was about showing the syntax of calling without the compilation error

Comment: @Miguel Prz, In that case, you forgot to mention you can also use `__PACKAGE__` as follows: `$x=__PACKAGE__;`, `print __PACKAGE__;`, `uc(__PACKAGE__)`, ...

Comment: bad advice, it has nothing to do with the question

Comment: @Miguel Prz, Exactly. Bad advice that has nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be misunderstanding of when [`__PACKAGE__`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Special-Literals) is treated as a [special literal](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Special-Literals).

The [special literals](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Special-Literals) only have their special meaning when they are a ["separate token"](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Special-Literals).

```
use 5.10.0;
use strict;
use warnings;

say 'in package: ', __PACKAGE__;

sub bar{ say 'this is the one you might be expecting' }

__PACKAGE__::bar(); # not a separate token

{
  package __PACKAGE__;
  sub bar{ say 'this is the one you actually get' }
}
```

```
in package: main
this is the one you actually get
```

There are a few ways to get around this:

```
bar(); # recommended

{
  no strict 'refs';
  *{__PACKAGE__.'::bar'}->(); # symbol ref

  ${__PACKAGE__.'::'}{bar}->(); # magical %package:: variable
}

__PACKAGE__->can('bar')->(); # may get 'bar' from a parent package

__PACKAGE__->bar(); # same as __PACKAGE__->can('bar')->(__PACKAGE__)


our $symbol_table = do{ no strict 'refs'; \%{__PACKAGE__.'::'} };

$symbol_table->{bar}->();
```

Really there is very rarely a good reason to use [`__PACKAGE__`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Special-Literals).

Comment: Note that term "special literal" is misleading. It's not any more special than `uc` or `time`.

Comment: `__PACKAGE__->can('bar')->();` is buggy. It's a method search, but you didn't provide the invocant.

Comment: @ikegami I used the term "special literal" since that's what the docs call it. (Also `__PACKAGE__()` didn't work until 5.16, which means that it was special) `__PACKAGE__->can('bar')->();` is buggy, in that it can get `bar` from a parent package. I assume that the OP didn't want to write it as a method, so calling it with an invocant would be just as wrong. It is abusing `UNIVERSAL->can` a bit. I may add `(\&{__PACKAGE__.'::bar'})->()` later if I think of anything else I want to change.

Comment: it is NOT abusing `can`, Brad your code is fine. You are using the `can` class method on the current package to get a reference to something inside the package, there is nothing wrong with that. Ikegami is wrong here.

Comment: @Joel Berger, What's wrong is that it can find a sub it shouldn't. Type of **bug** is called a *false positive*. Demonstration of bug: `perl -E'say NONEXISTENT->can('can') ? "not ok" : "ok"'` Read the documentation before spamming this misinformation any further!!!

Comment: maybe in the form "\_\_PACKAGE\_\_::Bar()" perl compiler can't  decide the tokent *\_\_PACKAGE\_\_* is a special literal or a custom package name ？

Comment: if so, i think perl should forbidden user to define package name as "\_\_PACKAGE\_\_"

Comment: @Chinaxing Why should it? You already got an error message when you used it wrong. Also what if Perl later returns an object blessed into the `__PACKAGE__` class when you call `__PACKAGE__`. You can actually create a subroutine of the same name `perl -E'sub __PACKAGE__{say "hi"};&__PACKAGE__()'` (It doesn't work the same … yet)

Comment: Why should Perl forbid the user from definining a package name with the same name as a function. Are you saying they should also prevent packages name `time` and `say`?

Comment: Re "maybe in the form `__PACKAGE__::Bar()` perl compiler can't decide the tokent `__PACKAGE__` is a special literal or a custom package name", No, it correctly knows its a part of the identifier `__PACKAGE__::Bar`. If it called `__PACKAGE__` as a function it would be deciding incorrectly.

Comment: \_\_PACKAGE\_\_ is a function ?

Comment: @Chinaxing `__PACKAGE__` acts similarly to a function. [In 5.16 you can now put empty parens after it `__PACKAGE__()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5160delta.html#__FILE__()-Syntax "perldoc perl5160delta")

Answer (score 4):

You appear to be mistaken. Both `Foo::bar()` and `__PACKAGE__::bar()` work exactly the same.

```
$ perl -e'sub Foo { "main" }  Foo::bar()'
Undefined subroutine &Foo::bar called at -e line 1.

$ perl -e'__PACKAGE__::bar()'
Undefined subroutine &__PACKAGE__::bar called at -e line 1.
```

and

```
$ perl -E'package Foo; sub bar { say "hello" } Foo::bar()'
hello

$ perl -E'package __PACKAGE__; sub bar { say "hello" } __PACKAGE__::bar()'
hello
```

They both call `bar` in the specified package (`Foo` and `__PACKAGE__`). Neither `Foo` nor `__PACKAGE__` is treated as a function call.

That's because neither `Foo` nor `__PACKAGE__` are bare words in your code. If you wanted to call `bar` from the package returned by `__PACKAGE__`, you can use

```
bar()
```

If you have a var with an arbitrary package (possibly obtained from `__PACKAGE__`), you can use

```
(\&{ $pkg . '::bar' })->();
```

Comment: $perl -e 'package Foo ; sub bar { print "hello\n" } ; Foo::bar()' 
hello

Comment: $perl -e 'package Foo ; sub bar { print "hello\n" } ; __PACKAGE__::bar()'   
Undefined subroutine &__PACKAGE__::bar called at -e line 1.

Comment: @Chinaxing, You forgot to change one of the `Foo` to `__PACKAGE__`. `$ perl -e 'package __PACKAGE__; sub bar { print "hello\n" } ; __PACKAGE__::bar()'` outputs `hello`.

Comment: Updated answer to reflect your udpate, but the answer is still the same. You never get the current package from `__PACKAGE__` because you never call `__PACKAGE__`. You have a sub call for the a sub named `bar` in the `__PACKAGE__` namespace.

Comment: the \_\_PACKAGE\_\_ in perl has special mean : the current Package, which will be compiled to the Current pakcage name : Foo; no one want to define the package \_\_PACKAGE\_\_ , that's not my mean

Comment: \_\_PACKAGE\_\_->bar is same to Foo->bar; all of them will be same to bar("Foo",), the "Foo" as first argument. I mean the "\_\_PACKAGE\_\_"will be same to the current package's name, here is "Foo"

Comment: Do you think that `for::bar()` is a for loop? It's not, `for` is part of the identifier `foo::bar`. Yes, `__PACKAGE__` returns `Foo` when you call it, but you didn't call it in your code. `__PACKAGE__::bar` doesn't call `__PACKAGE__` any more than `print "__PACKAGE__";` does.

Comment: Try `perl -E'say for Foo, __PACKAGE__, time, Foo::bar, __PACKAGE__::bar, time::bar'`

Answer (score 0):

The canonical way to search for a function (possibly a method) in a package (including in `__PACKAGE__`) is to use the `can` method. When called on a class name or instance, it returns a reference to the function/method; you can then dereference it to call the actual function. In your case this can be

```
perl -E 'sub bar { say "hello" } __PACKAGE__->can("bar")->()'
```

The difference between this and what Michael Prz suggests in the comments is the handling of the first argument. For example when you try

```
perl -E 'sub bar { say "hello " . shift } __PACKAGE__->bar("name")'
```

you get

```
hello main
```

since main is the invoking argument. However

```
perl -E 'sub bar { say "hello " . shift } __PACKAGE__->can("bar")->("name")'
```

does what you expect.

Comment: `can` is a method search. Unfortunately, the OP's code didn't ask for a method all.

Comment: `can` is a package search for methods AND functions. This is obvious since they are only different in their arguments. My comment was specifically directed against the comments from Michael Prz. I sure hope you didn't downvote this. This mechanism always works. `package __PACKAGE__`?? are you kidding?

Comment: No, you can't prevent it from doing a method search. What has different arguments? The sub called? What does that have to do with `can` finding the wrong sub?

Comment: @ikegami, you are normally spot-on with your Perl knowledge, in this case though, you don't seem to get it. `__PACKAGE__` is a special token that when used as a separate token returns the name of the current package. Therefore you cannot use it as `__PACKAGE__::bar()` since there it is part of a larger token, but you may use it as `__PACKAGE__->can("foo")` since the `->` starts a new token. In this way, if you want to call a FUNCTION by using the `__PACKAGE__` token, you can use `can` to get a reference to it, without using `no strict 'refs'`.

Comment: and if you should call it as `__PACKAGE__->bar` which also would find the `bar` method in the current package, it adds the package name to `@_` since you are using it as a class method. I KNOW that the op isn't asking about methods, which is why I caution AGAINST that.

Comment: That `__PACKAGE__::bar()` doesn't call `bar` from the package returned by `__PACKAGE__` and that you can't drive on the left-hand side of the road in Canada doesn't make `__PACKAGE__->can("foo")` correct. Your reasoning is invalid (false dichotomy.) See my answer and Brad's for three ways where you can call `foo` for some arbitrary package `$pkg`. (Of course, `bar()` is the correct way of calling `bar` in the package returned by `__PACKAGE__`.)

Comment: Your response is "don't because I said so" and you are wrong. You haven't provided any reason not to. Like it or not, Perl makes no distinction between a class and a package. I provide no dichotomy, I provide logic. You provide dichotomy where there is none.

Comment: huh? I did explain why it was buggy. I even provided code that demonstrated the bug. Now you're just throwing a tantrum.

Comment: "`__PACKAGE__->can('bar')->();` is buggy. It's a method search, but you didn't provide the invocant", the reason I do this is to NOT provide an invocant, we are calling a function not a method (per the OP). This isn't a bug, its a feature. Yes you can call `bar()`. That wasn't the question, it was why doesn't `__PACKAGE__::bar()` work. It doesn't. I provided a mechanism to use `__PACKAGE__` in a similar manner. End of story.

Comment: That's a bug in your code, not the problem with using `can`. The problem with using `can` is that it performs a method search. It can find a sub it shouldn't. In case you're not merely playing dumb, I shall repeat:  What's wrong is that it can find a sub it shouldn't. That type of **bug** is called a false positive. Demonstration of bug: `perl -E'say NONEXISTENT->can('can') ? "not ok" : "ok"'` Read the documentation before spamming this misinformation any further!!!

Comment: In summary: If you use `can`, you must pass an invocant. If you don't want to pass an invocant, you can't use `can`.